# How to use Logstash filters to add a new column based on some rows of other column?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

Suppose I have a csv file looking like this:

```
cummulated_values
0
2
5
10
17
```

How can I use logstash filters to add a new "values" column, which rows are defined as ***values[n] := cummulated_values[n] - cummulated_values[n-1], where 0 < n <= total number of rows*** and ***values[0] := cummulated_values[0]***, where cummulated_values[n] means n-th row of "cummulated_values" column?
So the output table will look like this:

```
cummulated_values, values
0, 0
2, 2
5, 3
10, 5
17, 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement that using a ruby filter.

```
    csv { autodetect_column_names => true }
    ruby {
        code => '
            c = event.get("cummulated_values").to_i
            @values ||= c
            event.set("values", c - @values)
            @values = c
        '
    }
```

You need the order of events to be preserved and you need all the events to go through the same instance of the ruby filter. Therefore you must set pipeline.workers to 1, and verify that if pipeline.ordered is set then it is set to either auto or true (the default value is auto, so if you have not set it you will be OK).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it possible to avoid using ruby filter?(I have never used Ruby)

Comment: You could probably implement it using an aggregate filter, but that would just be a wrapper to get the ruby code run.